# Can a shared library loaded in Java call Java methods?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

Let's say I have a Java application that has the following class,

```
class Adder {
    public int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
}
```

If I load into Java a shared library (.so file) using `System.loadLibrary("libABC.so")`, can a native method in `libABC` invoke `adder.add(1,2)` where `adder` is an instantiation of `Adder`? If yes, an example/pointer in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If it is being invoked as a callback, yes it can.  https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html#zz-5.3

Comment: Please don't spam tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **Adder** class with *add()* method

```
class Adder {
    public int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
}
```

For example, we have an instance named **mAdder** in class **Demo**.

```
public class Demo {
    native void nativeEntry();
    Adder mAdder = new Adder();

    public static void main(String[] args){
            System.loadLibrary("JNIBridge");

            Demo demo = new Demo();         
            demo.nativeEntry();
    }
}
```

In JNI, **demo** object is stored in **thiz** pointer.
Use *GetObjectField()* to get **mAdder** from **thiz**.
Use *CallIntMethod()* to invoke *add()* method of **mAdder**.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//use command
//javah -jni Demo
//to generate jni method declaration
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Demo_nativeEntry(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    //thiz is the calling object
    //in java main(), we call: demo.nativeEntry()
    //so, thiz is demo object

    //get class Demo
    jclass demoCls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Demo");
    //get id of mAdder in Demo
    jfieldID adderField = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, demoCls, "mAdder", "LAdder;"); 

    //get object mAdder from object demo
    jobject adderObject = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, thiz, adderField); 

    //get class Adder
    jclass adderCls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Adder"); 
    //get id of method add in Adder
    jmethodID addMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, adderCls, "add", "(II)I"); 
    // (II)I: is signature of method Adder.add()
    // use command: 
    //javap -s -p Adder
    //to get method signature

    //call method add of object mAdder
    jint sum = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, adderObject, addMethod, 10, 20); 
    //sum = add(10,20)

    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
}
```

You can get full code at [here](https://github.com/maxterjy/jni-ndk-sample/tree/master/JNI_CallIntMethod).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and often even if **add** is a private method.

Comment: Could you please give an example or point me to the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: Not only that, JNI can be used to change the otherwise immutable values of objects such as `String` and `Integer`.  That can wreak all kinds of havoc...